# Using forio contour to plot points on a sphere

Tags: forio-contour

Can forio contour be used to plot points on a sphere so that the sphere can be rotated and zoomed?  Or do I need to do this in d3.js?  Or possibly some Juila package?  I would like to integrate this into a forio epicenter project and also make it interactive with the underlying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'plot points on a sphere', in any case, the 'sphere chart' is not part of the base functionality of Contour, but you can write an extension that does what you want. One important point is that Contour (and d3 in general) has native support for 2d shapes but not 3d shapes, so you'd have to implement projecting the sphere into 2d screen space.

If you can tell me a bit more about what you're trying to do, maybe I can be of more help. In the meantime, here's a simple example of an extension that plots points on a 2d circle (data is angles in this case)

http://jsfiddle.net/tmzsudv5/

```
Contour.export('round', function (data, layer, options) {
    var r = 100;
    var theta = 2 * Math.PI / 180;
    var centerX = options.chart.width / 2;
    var centerY = options.chart.height / 2;

    layer.selectAll('circle').data(data[0].data).enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'dot')
      .attr('r', 1)
      .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return r * Math.cos(d.y * theta) + centerX; })
      .attr('cy', function(d, i) { return r * Math.sin(d.y * theta) + centerY; });
});

var data = _.range(100).map(function(n) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 360); });

new Contour({
    el: '.chart',
})
.round(data)
.render();
```

Comment: I just began using stackoverflow and don't have enough points to post an image.  Ideally, I would like to create an interactive 3d sphere.  I understand from your answer that I can't do it with Contour or d3.  I appreciate your 2d projection idea, but that approach is a bit limiting.  Can you suggest a library that would be compatible with Julia and epicenter for creating interactive 3d objects?  Thank you.